# Export Users with group membership

Tags: soql, user, data-export, public-group

Is there a SOQL query or a method to extract all users, their profiles and group membership from Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to export all the info in one go. You can export Users, and their profile info in one query and users/group membership in another query, then join the info based on the User id.

This gives users and profile info:

```
select
    Id,
    Email,
    Name,
    Profile.Name
from User
```

This gives UserIds, and their Groups List:

```
 select
    UserOrGroupId,
    Group.Name
 from GroupMember
 where UserOrGroupId in (select id from user)
```

Now you need to combine these two datasets based on the Id.